# Exchange 2010 OWA customization - Add email header to web message

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I'm working on a customization to Microsoft Exchange 2010 Outlook Web Access (OWA) which has the requirement to add a email header to new messages created through the web interface.

At the moment the customization has been done by directly modifying the editmessage.aspx page located in the premium forms folder on the exchange server itself. Due to the nature of this type of modification access to the mail item is limited however some access to ASP.net is available.

My question is as follows: Is it possible to add a mail header to email messages created through OWA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded there is no native way to achieve this within the existing 2010 OWA framework without serious modification.

This requirement has been ditched from the project.